# Get-AdUser no acepting variable

Tags: powershell

im trying to pull out all the information regarding my domain admin adminsitrators

```
#set domains we are going to query  
$domains = 'mydomainname.com'
```

#first here i bring the sam accounts names

```
    Foreach ($domain in $domains)
    {
        $OUTPUT =Get-AdGroupMember  -identity “Domain Admins” -recursive -server  $domain  |
                 Select-Object -Property samAccountName|
                 Select samAccountName;

        $Outputs +=$OUTPUT;
        $OUTPUT |Export-CSV "C:\File\$($domain).csv" -NoTypeInformation ;

    }
    $OUTPUT #this print the sam accounts 


   

#here is the problem 

    Foreach ($user in $OUTPUT)
   { 
        $Users2 =Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -like '$OUTPUT'" -Properties *  
        $USER3 +=$Users2;
        $Users2 |Export-CSV "C:\File\$($domain)Userpop.csv" -NoTypeInformation ;
    }
```

Comment: so ... what is your Question? what is the problem? where is the error? what did not work as expected? ... **_details_** ... [*grin*]

Comment: Hi and welcome Mariano.  I see here a really good attempt, but still some work is needed with some of the fundamentals.  Check out your how your data is flowing here.  In the first ForEach loop you are assigning data to the variable $OUTPUT.  Each time that loop runs $OUTPUT is being overwritten with new data.  It looks like you try to solve this by capturing in $Outputs which is good, but still there are issues.  Later you have another foreach loop that tries to use $OUTPUT instead of $Outputs.  $OUTPUT will only contain data from the last loop run.  Powershell is fun isn't it?  Keep at it!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a problem with your filter.  Try changing that line as follows:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter " SamAccountName -like `"$($user.samaccountname)`" " -Properties *
```

It can't be `$OUTPUT` as that's an array.  Your loop variable is `$user` which is an object so you need the `.samaccountname` property.  The filter needs a string with the `-like` matching a quoted string, so you need `" to pass the quote through to the final string.

Your CSV output of `$user2` may not be what you expect either as each object is output to the same file.  Perhaps you mean to have a `-Append` or write them to different files?

You'll probably want to reset `$user3` as well.  Perhaps add `$user3 = @()` before that loop.

Answer (score 1):

You should always try to avoid adding to arrays with `$array += $something`, because that means the **entire** array gets rebuild in memory, costing time and resources.

Also, I would advise using more descriptive variable names, so the code will still be understandable after some time.

Then, because you are getting info from different domains, it is important to store the domain name in the first loop together with the samaccount names, so you can use these as `-Server` parameter in the second loop on `Get-ADUser`

Try

```
#set domains we are going to query  
$domains = @('mydomainname.com')  # since there is only one domain listed, use @() to force it into an array

$domainsAndAdmins = foreach ($domain in $domains) {
    # store the SamAccountNames for this domain as objects in an array
    $admins = Get-AdGroupMember -Identity 'Domain Admins' -Recursive -Server $domain  |
              Select-Object -Property SamAccountName
    # export this to csv file
    $outFile = 'C:\File\{0}.csv' -f $domain
    $admins | Export-Csv $outFile -NoTypeInformation

    # output an object with both the domain and the array of SamAccountNames
    # this will be captured in variable $domainsAndAdmins
    [PsCustomObject]@{Domain = $domain; Admins = $admins.SamAccountName }
}

# output on screen
$domainsAndAdmins | Format-Table -AutoSize

# will result in something like
#
# Domain                 Admins                    
# ------                 ------                    
# mydomainname.com       {jdoe, jbloggs, mpimentel}
# myseconddomainname.com {jdoe, mpimentel}   

# next get ALL (?) properties from the users we found
$domainsAndAdmins | ForEach-Object {
    $domain = $_.Domain
    $result = foreach ($user in $_.Admins) {
        Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -like '$user'" -Server $domain -Properties * -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
    $outFile = 'C:\File\{0}_Userpop.csv' -f $domain
    $result | Export-Csv $outFile -NoTypeInformation
}
```